# error while freeing memory - C

Tags: c, free

I have a problem with this code:

```
 char * findAlphabet(char *string)
{
    char *tmp_alph = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
    char *alphabet = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
    strcpy(tmp_alph, string);
    qsort(tmp_alph, strlen(string) - 1, sizeof(char), strcmp);
    int i = 1, k = 1;
    alphabet[0] = tmp_alph[0];
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(string); ++i)
    {
        if(tmp_alph[i] != tmp_alph[i - 1])
        {
            alphabet[k++] = tmp_alph[i];
        }
    }
    alphabet[k - 1] = tmp_alph[strlen(string) - 1]; //Terminator
    alphabet[k] = '\0';
    free(tmp_alph);
    return alphabet;
}
```

Executing it with:

```
char *string = "ABBDDECACDABBDDFCACDAACACABBDDECACDBBCC$\0";
```

I have the following error:

```
malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000001a4ed50 ***
```

With a debugger it seems that the problem appears executing:

```
free(tmp_alph);
```

What's wrong with this code?

If I comment free(tmp_alph) the result seems to be correct.

Comment: `strcpy(tmp_alph, string);` tries to write a 0-terminator but there's no room for it. You need to allocate `strlen(string) + 1` characters.

Comment: It should also be noted that the compiler adds a `\0` for you when you use `""`.

Comment: Do you want a string that is a sorted version of the input?

Comment: Thank you all, it was a very stupid error(and question)! Unfortunately this code has worked for one week before raising this error!

Comment: I wonder how it can have done that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strlen(string)` returns the length of `string` ignoring the terminator character `\0`. When allocating space for `tmp_alph` you should consider that this string must also have the terminator character, so you have to explicitly declare an additional position in the array.

```
char *tmp_alph = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(string)+1));
```

I would also put manually the terminator character in `tmp_alph`, just in case `strcpy` does not do this automatically.

```
tmp_alph[strlen(string)+1] = '\0';
```